# Basic calculus question about epidemic modeling

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am a medical student attempting to build mathematical models of disease, but am struggling with the calculus. In particular, I am very confused by this equation shown in attached photo, and feel worse because it is called "elementary". How is the second equation the integral of the first?

Feel free to ignore the first sentence, before "we consider."

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equation is equivalent to

$$\frac{du}{ds}=-\alpha u.$$

This is a separable differential equation. In particular,

$$
\begin{align*}
&\frac{du}{ds}=-\alpha u \\ 
\Rightarrow & \frac{1}{u} du=-\alpha  \,ds \\
\Rightarrow & \int \frac{1}{u} du=\int -\alpha \,ds \\
\Rightarrow & \ln u =-\alpha s+c_1 \\
\Rightarrow & e^{\ln u}=e^{-\alpha s +c_1} \\
\Rightarrow & u(s)=c_2e^{-\alpha s}.
\end{align*}
$$

Now using your initial condition, probably $u(0)=0$, we arrive at $c_2=u(0)$, hence your solution,

$$u(s)=u(0)e^{-\alpha s}.$$

Comment: Glad I could help. Best of luck with your studies. :)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $u'=-\alpha u$ implies $(\ln(u))'=\frac{u'}{u}=-\alpha$. Now try integrating both sides.